# How to scale my custom cursor on anchor tag hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a custom cursor with html, css and js. And i want the cursor to scale up its normal width whenever i hover on any `<a></a>`  element on my web page. Can anyone please give a quick hint on how to go with it

Below is the html, css and js

HTML

`<div class="cursor-custom"></div>`

CSS

````
.cursor-custom {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781);
  // background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.877);
  border-radius: 50%;
  // z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}```

JS

```$("* a").hover(function(){
  $("cursor-custom").css({
   "width" : "40px;",
   "height" : "40px;"
  });
  })
````

i tried using javascript hover state to change the size of the custom cursor but it did'nt work

Comment: What's "normal width"? What's your current code?

Comment: The width and height of my cursor is `20px`

Comment: Could you add the JS which you mention but doesn't seem to be in the question.

Comment: Looking at the link you have given to @toastrackegnima it looks as though they have an element following the cursor rather than actually changing the cursor image - you can see how the standard cursor pointer/hand are still there and there's occasional lag on the circle moving. Would a similar set up be suitable for you. Can we see your cursor image?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) which allows you to change the size of a loaded custom cursor.

Instead, you could make another copy of your cursor's image file, resize it in your image editor, and then swap the cursor file used when you hover over the link, e.g.

```css
body {
    cursor: url("cursor.png");
}

a {
    cursor: url("cursor-big.png");
}
```

---

Since OP has now clarified their cursor is handled via JS instead of CSS, the problem changes a little.

The main thing is figuring out "are we hovering an `<a>` tag". We can find this out thanks to the [`Event.composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) method, which gives as an array containing the full top-down HTML structure of the element which is being hovered over.

Here's an example:

```js
let cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
let size;
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev)=>{
    let path = ev.composedPath();
    
    if (path.some(x=>x.tagName == "A")) size = 20;
    else size = 10;
    
    cursor.style.left   = (ev.clientX - size/2) + "px";
    cursor.style.top    = (ev.clientY - size/2) + "px";
    cursor.style.width  = size + "px";
    cursor.style.height = size + "px";
});
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    cursor: none;
}

#cursor {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #03A9F4;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: width 0.2s linear, height 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
<h1>My article</h1>
<p>Some amazing content, and a <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a>!</p>
```

Comment: The cursor was created with jquery and not css...default cursor still was set to `none`....i tracked the cursor movement with jquery `clientX` and `clientY` jquery properties and created a circle with css to follow the move, now i want the circle to scale up when i hover on any `<a></a>` tag......An example of what i want to achieve can be found in this link  (https://malvah.co)

Comment: @O.smithEffizzy'sTech I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

An image being used for a CSS cursor has limits on its size. These limits vary as between browsers and the recommendation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) is:

> In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px.
>
> Larger cursor images are ignored.
>
> However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum
> compatibility with operating systems and platforms.

So it is not possible to use an image for the cursor and just make it bigger (e.g. by using a bigger version of the same image from a file).

The question talks of using an image for the cursor but gives CSS styling for it so I assume that it has a 'normal' cursor plus an element that follows the cursor through the use of JS.
It is reasonable therefore that JS be used to test whether the cursor is over an anchor element and if so to change the size of the element that is following the cursor, as discussed in the answer given by @toastrackenigma.

However, now we have seen the site that has an example of what is required (malvah.co) it is possible to go quite a way to emulate this using just CSS.

Anchor tags are styled to have an after pseudo element on hover which calculates a suitable diameter for a circle depending on the length of the text being hovered (and a maximum so the circle doesn't swamp the whole page!) and centers it on that text.

In this snippet he cursor is replaced with an image of a circle when not in this hover situation, but of course existing code for having a circle track the normal cursor could be used.

Note: to see the effect of varying circle size run snippet in full page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Circle cursor</title>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/circle.png), auto;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2vmin;
  top: 50vh;
}
a:hover::after {
  --maxr: 15vmin; /* the maximum radius you will allow the circle to be on hover */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * (var(--maxr) * 0.9));
  left: -1em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, transparent 0%, transparent 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781) 90%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781) calc(90%  + 3px), transparent calc(90% + 3px));
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% + 2em);
  height: calc(var(--maxr) * 2);
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: expand 150ms ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">hover here</a>
<a href="#">hover here on a longer text</a>
<a href="#">hover here on a much much longer text</a>
</body>
<!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034999/how-to-scale-my-custom-cursor-on-anchor-tag-hover

from: 
-->
</html>
```

Comment: The cursor i have is a different element entirely from the browsers cursor and thats what i want to be changed in mouse hover state on an `<a></a> `

Comment: Understood - I just used a linear-gradient as I didn't have your image. If you'd like to post a link to your image then we can alter the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to pull through with regular jquery `mouseover` and `mouseleave` method, Below i what I did

JS

```
    $(".cursor-custom").addClass("hovered");
  });
  $("a").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".cursor-custom").removeClass("hovered");
  });
```

CSS

```
.cursor-custom {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.781);
  // background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.877);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.hovered {
  transform: scale(5);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  // color: red;
}
```

Using the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` method, i was able to detect the hover state of any `<a></a>` element on my webpage, then a added a class to the custom-cursor element i wanted to scale up with `addClass` method. Thanks guys for all your support.