# Make a custom cursor scale with the rendered document size (+its offset)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the `cursor : url('./path/to/small-image.png') X Y, grab` to set a custom image as my cursor, with an offset because I use a particular point of that image as a pointer (and a fallback value being the grab cursor).

When I render the page on a larger/smaller screen, naturally, the cursor stays the same size, and looks either tiny or gigantic compared to the page's content.

**How could I make the cursor scale with the page ? If that's possible, how could I make sure the offset (cursor image corner to pointer distance) is proportionally the same ?**

The [mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) doesn't list a size / scale attribute.
I've had no luck with computing offset (using `50%` or `calc(50%)` fails), so even that is out for me.

[How to scale my custom cursor on anchor tag hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034999/how-to-scale-my-custom-cursor-on-anchor-tag-hover) does say that there is nothing in the cursor spec allowing for an easy on-the-fly scaling, but I'm looking for something I think is more static, so maybe there's a solution ?
Maybe all browsers now implement something cool with cursors ?

Am I stuck with pre-making tons of different scale cursors and trying to select the right one once I've determined the rendered page's size ?

### Problem

Here's a jsfiddle with a simple reduction of my problem

https://jsfiddle.net/bnjprevL/28/

I'll consider this question answered if someone can either show a method to solve the problem in the jsfiddle, or confirm that using a lot of precomputed sizes is indeed the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Ok, I got a mad idea, you will know what I thought by watching the code below.

```js
function scaleImage(scale, imageUrl, callback) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image();

  img.onload = function () {
    const finalWidth = img.width * scale;
    const finalHeight = img.height * scale;

    canvas.width = finalWidth;
    canvas.height = finalHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);

    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

    callback(dataURL);
  };

  img.src = imageUrl;
}

 window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

    // Notice, the origin of the image url must be the same as your site, or using base64 data. 
    const cursorUrl ='';
    // 1920 is just a supposed value, you can change it to what you wanted
    const scale = innerWidth / 1920;

    scaleImage(scale, cursorUrl, dataURL => {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'url(' + dataURL + ') 0 0, grab';
    });
  });
```

The code above has more points to be optimized, whatever, now you can achieve your goal.

Before:

---

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries) to achieve this by setting different styles on screens with different sizes.

The code below shows how to do it:

```css
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
cursor : url('./path/to/small-image.png') X Y, grab;

}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
cursor : url('./path/to/small-image.png') X1 Y1, grab;
}

// ...and so on
```

The problem now becomes what the min-width value is or how can I set the min-width value. Fortunately, The Bootstrap has a good practice, click [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints) to get more details.

Comment: Updated the question.
Thanks for you answer, but that's a solution I had already though of (and wasn't satisfied with).

Can you either :

- expand on a more convenient way to use it (which would be an improvement,

- or confirm it is the only way to acomplish my task 
?

Comment: Redrawing a scaled image using a canvas and then using that as a custom pointer, very elegant, thanks. (I do consider this a "more convenient way" of using media queries, so I'll accept the answer)